# How Do You Clear the macOS Terminal Pad In Visual Studio For Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

I'm debugging a C# console application using Visual Studio for the Mac. I'm using frequent `Console.WriteLine()` statements.

Is there anyway to clear the output of the `Terminal - macOS` pad where the `Console` output is displayed **every time** I run / debug the program? I've tried calls to `Console.Clear()` to no effect. I have seen suggestions to use `Cmd-K` but that doesn't work. Other suggestions are all for VSCode, not Visual Studio.

[image]

Surely I can't be the only one who finds seeing the old output distracting when debugging?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I tried all the below suggestions to no avail.

Answer (score 11):

You aren't alone. I was just wondering why it didn't clear the screen either. There is an option to use Terminal, instead of the built in terminal. Check under Preferences > Terminal, then remove the check mark next to "Enable Integrated Terminal" and it will just pop up in a normal terminal which doesn't seem to have that issue. If you figure something else out let me know though.

Comment: No solution but thanks for the tip - it's a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You may deactivate and reactivate the integrated terminal in : preferences\terminal options\uncheck\check. You may have to close VSFM between the uncheck\check process in order to clear the entre data. That way, it does clear the terminal data, but I would prefer some fast “clear” kind of short-cut options instead.

Have a good one.

Prog

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a workaround:

`Console.Write("\f\u001bc\x1b[3J");`

replace `Console.Clear()` with the above

Answer (score -1):

Close the terminal window, then the next run will open an empty one.

Comment: does not work, it does not clear its contents

Answer (score -1):

I call Console.Clear() at first line each time Run project

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for the solution as I couldn't figure it out for the life of me, tried 'cmd + k' and it worked.
I could have sworn I'd tried it in the past with no success.
Maybe a few points that will help:

- Have the terminal selected.
- The terminal line has to empty.

New to coding, first stack overflow comment, hope this has some value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).